# Why are my python imports breaking in different subdirectories?

Tags: python, import, project

I am currently facing an issue with python class imports and having trouble figuring out what I am doing wrong. I find it strange that imports can work within their directory well and break when calling from another directory. Let me replicate the problem below.

Suppose I have a main directory and it looks something like this:

```
testing-framework
 ┣ sheetnum_classification
 ┃ ┣ documentation
 ┃ ┃ ┗  readme.md
 ┃ ┣ utils
 ┃ ┃ ┣  __init__.py
 ┃ ┃ ┣  assign_domain.py
 ┃ ┃ ┗  text_modification.py
 ┃ ┣  classify_sheetnum.py
 ┃ ┗ tests.ipynb
 ┗  ClassifySheetNumbers.ipynb
```

Basically, the package `sheetnum_classification` has the python file `classify_sheetnum.py` which references its utility classes in utils.

When working within the package directory `sheetnum_classification`, the following import within `classify_sheetnum.py` works fine.

```py
from utils.text_modification import TextModifications
from utils.assign_domain import AssignDomain
```

However, when trying to import `classify_sheetnum.py` from the `ClassifySheetNumbers.ipynb` in the outer main directory, I always get an error from the notebook saying the following.

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 4
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 import numpy as np
----> 4 from sheetnum_classification.classify_sheetnum import SheetNumberClassification

File ~/Desktop/testing framework/sheetnum_classification/classify_sheetnum.py:2
      1 # Helper Class Imports
----> 2 from utils.text_modification import TextModifications
      3 from utils.assign_domain import AssignDomain
      5 class SheetNumberClassification:
      6     # Provides a Classification based on Sheet Number Text

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

Then, I changed the imports within the package to the following which allowed everything to work within the outer directory but broke all of the imports within the inner directory.

```py
from .utils.text_modification import TextModifications
from .utils.assign_domain import AssignDomain
```

Why does each of the calls behave differently within different folders and how can I structure the package to not break when using the tests within the package and when it is called from outside of the package itself? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry if this is a beginner question, I am a college student struggling with project structuring greatly!

Answer (score 0):

Your import failed because `utils` package is not in `sys.path`.

There are some ways to fix your problem. My advice is:

1. Create an empty file `sheetnum_classification/__init__.py`
2. Update your `sys.path` in `ClassifySheetNumbers.ipynb`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
```

3. Change your imports:

```
from sheetnum_classification.utils.text_modification import TextModifications
from sheetnum_classification.utils.assign_domain import AssignDomain
```